# keytool is not an internal or external command

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I tried to run this command "keytool -genkey -v -keystore example.keystore -alias example -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000" 
It says  "keytool is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
I have checked the environmental variable and they are correct,
Any help could be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably, `keytool` is not in the `PATH` of your current command prompt window. If you updated the `PATH` environment variable via the Control Panel or equivalent means, AFAIK you need to open a fresh command prompt window for it to pick up the change.

Comment: Yes, I have opened fresh command prompt window but still the same error comes up

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bin folder inside your Java installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin) or similar,  and shift right click > Command prompt, now you are running the command where keytool actually is. Still get an error?

Comment: I saw my SDK tools folder and I didn't find any file with name keytool

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, it's in the Java folder actually. Path should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin`

Comment: Perfect!! It worked. but example.keystore should be in my project's android folder, right? So that I can use it while converting into .apk file

Comment: No you can place it anywhere you want, maybe off the C drive in case you reinstall windows later. Just make sure it's safe so that you could update your app on the Play Store later. In Android Studio you can point to its location. And by the way, I think you can create new keys if you lose yours, not a problem BUT that's if you haven't yet uploaded your app to the store. Once you do, the only way to update it is with the same key, otherwise you need to make a new project there. See this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks, and where should I execute this command for signing 

"jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name"

Comment: Jarsigner should be in the same folder - your java installation folder/bin. However, note that keytool exists in a JRE installation but jarsigner doesn't. You'd need to install java JDK. I myself had problems with the signing when trying to use those commands but it turned out that I didn't need it. Just follow the little tutorial in the link I gave you, under the title Signing Your App in Android Studio. It has a nice UI.

Comment: When I import my ionic project into android studio, I can't see the "generate signed apk" in build. Do I have to do anything else to get that option?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly it is available in the path, %JAVA_HOME%\bin.